# What are some techniques to monitor multiple instances of a piece of software?

Tags: .net, vb6, monitoring, kiosk, windows-embedded

I have a piece of self-serve kiosk software that will be running at multiple sites. I'd like to monitor their status remotely.

The kiosk application itself is pretty much finished. I am now in the process of creating a piece of software that will monitor all of the kiosks from a central location so that the customer can view particular details remotely (for instance, how many bills are in the acceptor's cash cartridge, what customer is currently logged in, etc.). Because I am in such an early stage of development, my options are quite open. I understand that I'm not giving very many qualifications, but I'd like to try to get a good variety of potential solutions. Some details:

- Kiosk software is a VB6 app running on Windows Embedded
- Monitoring software will be run on a modern desktop version of Windows (either XP, Vista, or 7)
- Database is SQL Server 2008

My initial idea was to develop a .NET app that would simply report the last database transaction for each kiosk at a set interval (say every second or so) but I'd really like for the kiosk software to report its status directly. I'm not exactly sure where to begin in terms of what modifications may need to be made to the kiosk software, and what the monitoring software will require. Links to articles on these topics would be most welcome.

Comment: This is an infrastructure question.  Connecting to a machine somewhere on planet Earth through the internet isn't that trivial unless you use a service like gotomypc or citydesk.  Ask at serverfault.com

Comment: Do you want these individually managed remotely, or do you want them "phoning home" and reporting to a central database? For example there are HTTP server controls for VB6 to embed a Web server right in the program, but this means having a client either "pull" pages or make WS-like calls - so the embedded machine would require Internet exposure.

Answer (score 0):

If the software was written in .Net, I would suggest remoting it to poll the status, but that option is out. You could possibly use another table to log the current statuses of each of the workstations. That way, you would just update the record for that kiosk (or records, depending on how you design the database) and the monitor app would query the database every so often. If you want realtime, then this isn't the solution.

Comment: Yes, this was my initial thought as well. While I still may take this approach, I thought there may be a more robust solution. I'm looking into the Winsock control in VB6, but I still may end up simply reading the latest database transactions in a .NET monitoring app.