# Monitoring SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, monitoring

I'm seeking for a solution to monitor (with graphs) the status of my MSSQL instances during a periode of time (day or night) and get or make reports for that monitoring.

Does any one have or know any known simple solutions to do so please ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580465/what-are-some-techniques-to-monitor-multiple-instances-of-a-piece-of-software

Comment: I don't really see where is matchs with my request...but thanks

Comment: This is probably a question for the DBA site, unless you plan on programming your own tools (and maybe even if you do). But there are so many tools available for monitoring that it's almost certainly simplest and cheapest to use something that already exists.

Comment: How can I ask this question in the DBA section ?

Comment: @Othmankun http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If your SQLServer version is or above 2008. There is something called as Data Collector(http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677248(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you want to monitor.  There are vendor products that will do it.  Idera has Diagnostic Manager and RedGate has SQL Monitor to name just a few.  Or if you don't want to spend any money SQL Server has several monitoring options including alerts, policy based management and data collection.  These won't be as pretty and may not cover as much not to mention you will be writing some code on your own, but they are free (with SQL Server of course, depending on edition).

Answer (score 0):

Related, though you'll want to edit the scripts for getting information is Ola Hallengren's maintenance solutions  http://ola.hallengren.com/.  There are useful scripts for maintenance, but depending on what information you're trying to obtain, you can build on these scripts to get information.  From there, you can use the results of these queries in SSRS to populate graphs, or even use a tool like Excel.

Again, Ola Hallengren provides maintenance solutions, so these will need to be adjusted for monitoring (depending on what you're monitoring), but they are totally free and you can edit the scripts, as well as see where the information comes from so that you can determine what you need to monitor.